# Cannot set up Source Image when building a nodeJs serverless application in Vercel

Tags: node.js, image, serverless, vercel-middleware

I'm having a serious problem when trying to configure the loading of an image in a serverless project with nodeJs.

My project has the image in the public folder and I am using the express middleware to indicate the public folder.

My image loads normally in local development, however when deploying to Vercel the image does not load, and it opens normally in the project source.

In the console I only see the 404 error when loading the image.

Note:
Loading JSON linked to the database also runs normally.

Example
https://vinao-nodejs.vercel.app/

Steps to Reproduce

````
```import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config(); import express from 'express'; import { kv } from '@vercel/kv';

const app = express(); const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// Adicione o middleware para servir arquivos estáticos (CSS) app.use(express.static('public')); app.use('/images', express.static('images'));

app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(API listen on PORT ${PORT}); });

app.get('/', async (req, res) => { try { const user = await getUserData();

const pageTitle = 'Vinao World';
const content = `
    <html>
    <head>
    
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>${pageTitle}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${pageTitle}</h1>
       
        
        <div>
            <img src="/images/logo.png">
        </div>

        <pre>${JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre>
    </body>
    </html>
`;
res.send(content);

} catch (error) { console.error(error); res.status(500).send('Erro ao obter dados do usuário.'); } });

async function getUserData() { try { const user = await kv.hgetall('user:vinao'); console.log('Dados do usuário obtidos com sucesso:', user); return user; } catch (error) { console.error('Erro ao obter dados do usuário:', error); throw error; } }```
````